# Soap errors when using Remote Server with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I know this is long shot but I was hoping for some guidance.

I have a WCF web service which when debugging locally works fine. As soon as I publish it to an IIS server it falls over with a message which tells me there is a SOAP error. I can connect to the services fine though a browser. I tried setting up remote debugging but it doesn't seem to be getting that far. I set up a web debugger and got this.

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

I know it's nothing to do with the Web.config file because I am using WCF 4.0 simplified configuration so you don't need to set an endpoint.

I have set `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` but I am not getting anything else back. I was hoping someone else has had similar problems after publishing and can at least point me in the right direction.

I also tried full IIS locally and had the same problem.

Comment: You might want to active the trace to get more informations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Check the event log on your IIS server, there might be some more info?

Comment: Logging is not giving me anything and already checked the event log and again nothing useful. :(

Comment: Enable IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults and check response in fiddler. You will get exception details. Also check event log on server, there you may get some hints.

Comment: I got it work by removing the <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" /> I have no idea of the impact.